# Mysql 5.7.20 crashes after jemalloc installation

Tags: mysql, crash

Recently i faced memory leak issue in one my mysql instance (5.7.20) where eventhough allocated buffer pool size was 50% of the RAM, but mysqld memory utilization was constantly pegging at 90%.
I found similar bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83047 and in my case also bulk load is the predominant workload.
So i installed jemalloc and made changes to /etc/sysconfig/mysql so the mysqld uses jemalloc instead of malloc().

My memory leak issue is fixed now. But after this change i am noticing that mysql crashes often and from error log i could not interpret what is exactly causing the crash.

> 01:08:08 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ; This could be because you hit a
>   bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it
>   was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured.
>   This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware. Attempting
>   to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem. As
>   this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
>   collection process might fail.
>
> key_buffer_size=8388608 read_buffer_size=131072
>   max_used_connections=18 max_threads=151 thread_count=16
>   connection_count=16 It is possible that mysqld could use up to
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   338785 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
>   variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x7f6f6bc16000 Attempting backtrace. You can use the
>   following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no
>   messages after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom =
>   7f86e055ce30 thread_stack 0x40000
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xef8feb]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x461)[0x7b0191]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf5e0)[0x7f86fee6b5e0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z32innobase_parse_hint_from_commentP3THDP12dict_table_tPK11TABLE_SHARE+0x2d0)[0xf2ed50] /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN19create_table_info_t24create_table_update_dictEv+0x119)[0xf41c09]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11ha_innobase6createEPKcP5TABLEP24st_ha_create_information+0x127)[0xf436b7]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11ha_innopart20create_new_partitionEP5TABLEP24st_ha_create_informationPKcjP17partition_element+0xcd)[0xf53aad]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN16Partition_helper17change_partitionsEP24st_ha_create_informationPKcPyS4_+0x489)[0xc255d9]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xcccdee]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z26fast_alter_partition_tableP3THDP5TABLEP10Alter_infoP24st_ha_create_informationP10TABLE_LISTPcPKcP14partition_info+0x52c)[0xcd78cc]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z17mysql_alter_tableP3THDPKcS2_P24st_ha_create_informationP10TABLE_LISTP10Alter_info+0xd43)[0xd309e3]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN19Sql_cmd_alter_table7executeEP3THD+0x4f8)[0xe2e648]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x5d0)[0xcc35d0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN18Prepared_statement7executeEP6Stringb+0x357)[0xcf1397]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN18Prepared_statement12execute_loopEP6StringbPhS2_+0xda)[0xcf43ca]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z22mysql_sql_stmt_executeP3THD+0xfc)[0xcf48ac]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x198d)[0xcc498d]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x50)[0xc4a1b0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjb+0x3fc)[0xc4be6c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr29validate_lex_and_execute_coreEP3THDPjb+0xbb)[0xc4c85b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt7executeEP3THDPj+0x128)[0xc4da08]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x4f4)[0xc45a04]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head17execute_procedureEP3THDP4ListI4ItemE+0x777)[0xc49567]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x1c42)[0xcc4c42]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x50)[0xc4a1b0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjb+0x3fc)[0xc4be6c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr29validate_lex_and_execute_coreEP3THDPjb+0xbb)[0xc4c85b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt7executeEP3THDPj+0x128)[0xc4da08]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x4f4)[0xc45a04]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head17execute_procedureEP3THDP4ListI4ItemE+0x777)[0xc49567]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x1c42)[0xcc4c42]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x50)[0xc4a1b0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjb+0x3fc)[0xc4be6c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr29validate_lex_and_execute_coreEP3THDPjb+0xbb)[0xc4c85b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt7executeEP3THDPj+0x128)[0xc4da08]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x4f4)[0xc45a04]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head17execute_procedureEP3THDP4ListI4ItemE+0x777)[0xc49567]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x1c42)[0xcc4c42]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x50)[0xc4a1b0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjb+0x3fc)[0xc4be6c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN12sp_lex_instr29validate_lex_and_execute_coreEP3THDPjb+0xbb)[0xc4c85b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_instr_stmt7executeEP3THDPj+0x128)[0xc4da08]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x4f4)[0xc45a04]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head17execute_procedureEP3THDP4ListI4ItemE+0x777)[0xc49567]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x1c42)[0xcc4c42]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x3b5)[0xcc99a5]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0xa8a)[0xcca4aa]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x19f)[0xccbeef]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x288)[0xd8b668]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0x126f4a4]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25)[0x7f86fee63e25]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f86fd92034d]
>
> Trying to get some variables. Some pointers may be invalid and cause
>   the dump to abort. Query (7f69a47be040): ALTER TABLE HN_QOS_DATA_0666
>   ADD PARTITION(  partition p737487 values less than ( '2019-03-04' ))
>   Connection ID (thread ID): 51548 Status: NOT_KILLED
>
> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html
>   contains information that should help you find out what is causing the
>   crash.

and then the recovery starts

> 2019-02-02T01:08:26.053673Z 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of
>   max_open_files to more than 10000 (request: 10161)
>   2019-02-02T01:08:26.054509Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits:
>   table_open_cache: 4919 (requested 5000) 2019-02-02T01:08:26.252510Z 0
>   [Warning] The syntax '--log_warnings/-W' is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future release. Please use '--log_error_verbosity'
>   instead. 2019-02-02T01:08:26.252626Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with
>   implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>   --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2019-02-02T01:08:26.252704Z 0 [Warning] Insecure
>   configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict
>   location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty
>   path. InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
>   15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
>   38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
>   61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
>   84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99

I have PMM monitoring for this instance, i can certainly see a spike in swapping, IO and spike in some other charts as well. But im not able come to a conclusion on what is causing the crash. Whether a particular query is causing or it is because of memory pressure or for some other reason.

Even during the memory leak issue in the server, mysql never crashed but after started using jemalloc, mysql just crashes .

1) what things should i look upon to find the exact cause of mysql crash (mysql and in PMM)
2) Does using jemalloc library causes mysql crashes
3) How can i rule out memory pressure as a cause of crash
4) Is it better to use tcmalloc() instead of jemalloc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much RAM?  Is Java involved?

Comment: Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Consider thread_cache_size=100 in your my.cnf [mysqld] section to reduce THREAD PRESSURE.

Comment: Please post results of SHOW CREATE TABLE  HN_QOS_DATA_0666; since this is the table that was in use when a PARTITION CREATE was being attempted according to your documentation provided.

Comment: Does the ADD PARTITION( partition p737487 values ...  look odd from this snippet?  ADD PARTITION( partition p737487 values less than ( '2019-03-04' ))

Comment: Hi .. 80 GB allocated out of total 125 GB. HN_QOS_DATA_0666 is table captured in that instance which i shared. Every time crash is happening, table is different not the same..but i will share the show create soon.

Comment: No Java involved. As i said earlier, i have installed jemalloc library recently to alleviate memory leak issue. Its database created by Nimsoft monitoring tool

Comment: With 125GB RAM available, make your thread_cache_size=256  Please and post the other data requested when you have time, including the SHOW CREATE TABLE HN_QOS_DATA_0666; when time permits.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for for time.. Looks like jemalloc() and vm.swappiness=1 does not go well i guess. I used TCmalloc() library and increased vm.swappiness=30 and Mysql is not crashing now (earlier it was crashing every 3 days)